# Windows Phone - Save a thumbnail preview into isolated storage of recorded video

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an app that I want to allow the user to record video and then save that video along with an image that represents that video into isolated storage.  I have the video part figured out from some sample code here:

```
' Set recording state: start recording.
Private Sub StartVideoRecording()
Try
         ...
    App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded = False

    ' Connect fileSink to captureSource.
    If captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice IsNot Nothing AndAlso captureSource.State = CaptureState.Started Then
        captureSource.Stop()

        ' Connect the input and output of fileSink.
        fileSink.CaptureSource = captureSource
        fileSink.IsolatedStorageFileName = isoVideoFileName
    End If

    ' Begin recording.
    If captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice IsNot Nothing AndAlso captureSource.State = CaptureState.Stopped Then
        captureSource.Start()
    End If

    ' Set the button states and the message.
    UpdateUI(ButtonState.Recording, "Recording...")


Catch e As Exception
    ' If recording fails, display an error.
    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() txtDebug.Text = "ERROR: " & e.Message.ToString())
End Try
End Sub

' Set the recording state: stop recording.
Private Sub StopVideoRecording()
Try
    ' Stop recording.
    If captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice IsNot Nothing AndAlso captureSource.State = CaptureState.Started Then
        captureSource.Stop()

        ' Disconnect fileSink.
        fileSink.CaptureSource = Nothing
        fileSink.IsolatedStorageFileName = Nothing

        ' Set the button states and the message.
        UpdateUI(ButtonState.NoChange, "Preparing viewfinder...")

        StartVideoPreview()
    End If
Catch e As Exception
    ' If stop fails, display an error.
    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() txtDebug.Text = "ERROR: " & e.Message.ToString())
End Try
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to automatically extract a thumbnail out of the recorded video without forcing the user to also take a picture?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be happy to know that there is an automatic thumbnail that is generated. The filename will have the .jpg extension. You can look for a IsolatedStorage browser to see the result.

Comment: I'm using windows phone power tools to browse and I don't see any jpg files generated...